# increasing and one one function

Tags: functions

If we are given a function f(x)=$x^3$$+$$3x$ for all x belong to real number .

Now as the derivative of function is always positive so the function should be increasing function and if it is always increasing function then it should be one one function also .

But when i tried , I got different result . Why ?

my try is on  https://i.stack.imgur.com/J28rp.jpg

Comment: Sorry , I cannot post image as I don't have enough reputations

Answer (score 1):

You obtained a contradiction because you put $x_1=x_2$ into the equality AFTER you divided it by $x_1-x_2$ !